# Is it possible to delete a GitHub package version and then replace it with a new version

Tags: github, node-modules, package-managers, github-package-registry

I've found that you can [delete a GitHub package version](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/deleting-and-restoring-a-package#deleting-a-package-version).

And you can also [restore a deleted package version](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/deleting-and-restoring-a-package#restoring-packages).

However, is it possible to delete a package version, but then publish an entirely new version in its place, with the same tag/version number?

The reason I need this is that I've accidentally published a pre-release with the wrong version name and tag, e.g. `v7.0.0`, instead of `v7.0.0-beta01`. And I would like to remove `v7.0.0`, so it can be replaced with the real final release version when ready.

Comment: I would guess not, because it would be too open to abuse.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was thinking that too - although their docs don't explicitly say that you can't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - at this time you can replace a deleted package on GitHub.

I recently did this with a particular version, deleted the package on GitHub and then rebuilt and redeployed.

I was able to publish a new package with the same version name as the previous one.